# I get a syntax error in IE but not in Chrome

Tags: javascript, cookies

So I have this code (a function) that works in Google Chrome/Fire Fox but not in IE. If I comment this certain line, everything runs fine, except that line is crucial.

I have this function called ReadCookie, which basically just stores the cookies into an array called cookiearray.

```
function ReadCookie() {

var allcookies = document.cookie; //variable called "allcookies" stores all the cookies.
cookiearray = allcookies.split(';').map(c => c.split('=')[1]); //cookiearray is an array that has all the values as strings.

}
```

IE said that the 4th line is incorrect `cookiearray = allcookies.split(';').map(c => c.split('=')[1]);` but I don't know why.

Thanks!

Comment: you could also try a syntax from some future ES7 working draft for instance. If you really want your production code to work - you'll stick to using a standard JS syntax and methods instead.

Comment: @BekimBacaj Or using a transpiler.. :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it's an ECMA script 6 [thing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) with the way you're using the map.

So you can write it like this instead:

```
cookiearray = allcookies.split(';').map(function (c) {
  return c.split('=')[1];
}); //cookiearray is an array that has all the values as strings.
```

Answer (score 4):

[Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) (like `c => c.split('=')[1]`) are a new feature in ES6. Chrome supports them. Internet Explorer does not.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I implemented was as follows

1. goto:  https://babeljs.io/repl
2. Paste in your code and select es2015.
3. In your new code paste the following, if you are using **forEach** (which is again not supported in IE) :

   if (window.NodeList && !NodeList.prototype.forEach) {
       NodeList.prototype.forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;
   }
4. Use **indexOf** instead of **includes**